# Getting IOException with HttpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode()

Tags: http, file-upload, io, httpurlconnection, java-io

I've written HttpUrlConnection wrapper. It supports file uploading, so I'm using HttpUrlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode() to prevent OutOfMemoryException.

But after writing all data to OutputStream I getting IOException. Without this method everything works fine.

Here the code:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = getConnection();
    if(!isSent) {
        OutputStream output;
        if(!files.isEmpty()) {
            connection.setRequestProperty(HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART);
            // Tried to add this line, but still not working
            connection.setRequestProperty("Transfer-Encoding","chunked");
            connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(chunkSize);
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            writeParamsMultipart(output);
            writeFilesMultipart(output);
            output.write((PREFIX + BOUNDARY + PREFIX + LINEND).getBytes());
        } else {
            connection.setRequestProperty(HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_TYPE_FORM);
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            output.write(paramsToUrlencoded(post).getBytes());
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        isSent = true;
    }
    // Getting exception on this line
    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    if(ENCODING_GZIP.equalsIgnoreCase(connection.getHeaderField(HEADER_CONTENT_ENCODING))) {
        input = new GZIPInputStream(input);
    }
    return input;
```

chunkSize by default 1024 bytes. What's the problem?

Comment: Can you please provide details on the exception that gets thrown?

Comment: @JohnSaxton surprisingly it's FileNotFoundException, but for URL.

    `java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://connectionUrl
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)`

Comment: Are you sure that the HTTP endpoint you're writing to supports chunked transfers? Can you write to it using cURL with chunked encoding?

Answer (score -2):

> It's `FileNotFoundException`

That means that the URL is incorrect. It's the equivalent of HTTP 403.

Nothing to do with chunked transfer mode.